# Replace a binary block within a large file

Tags: sed, replace, binary

I have a partition image that contains a 1MB file populated with random data, and  I would like to replace the contents of that file with another 1MB file populated with different random data.

I have done something similar before by creating a file with a known unique string and using sed to replace it e.g. `sed -i 's/foobar_corruptiontest/barfoo_corruptiontest/' partition.img`

For a solution I imagined something along the lines of:

```
head -c 1M </dev/urandom >fileA
head -c 1M </dev/urandom >fileB
binary_sed -i 's/<fileA/<fileB/' partition.img
```

I found a tool [bbe](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bbe) which purports to be a sedlike editor for binary files, but unless I am reading the man page wrong it doesn't seem to support file input?

Side-note: In case you are very confused why anyone would want to do this, the context is I am testing [verity](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/DMVerity) by corrupting a file in a predictable manner, but it should bear no relevance to the question. In fact please do not consider it in an answer.

Comment: The writing part should be easy as `dd if=fileB of=partition.img bs=1 seek=$OFFSET conv=notrunc`    It's getting $OFFSET that's the tricky part.  Sure , some variation on `grep --byte-offset ` could do it, if you wanted to create a pattern that matched a 1M file.

Comment: that's tricky but you can imagine combining dd if=samedevice skip=x count= ...| bbe ... | dd seek=x of=samedevice  . since input is read before being overwritten that should do it (have a backup...)

Answer (score 0):

I found a halfway decent solution, but unfortunately it requires a non-standard tool to search for the file offset. I hope that someone can come up with a better answer that only uses standard tools.

Install the tool [SearchBin](https://github.com/Sepero/SearchBin).

```
head -c 1M </dev/urandom >fileA
head -c 1M </dev/urandom >fileB
OFFSET=$(searchbin -f fileA -m 1 partition.img | head -1 | awk '{print $4}')
dd if=fileB of=paritition.img bs=1 seek=${OFFSET} conv=notrunc
```